# Using boost::future .then() to add a continuation task to the same thread pool

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, threadpool, boost-asio

I am fairly new to Boost. I am using the Boost 1.72.0. I am trying to explore boost::asio::thread_pool and posting tasks to it as per the [documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.futures.reference.unique_future.then). I try to post a continuation to the posted task as follows:

1. Using boost::launch::executor policy:

```
fut.then(boost::launch::executor, [](boost::future<void> res) {

        std::thread::id this_id = std::this_thread::get_id();
        std::cout << "\nThread Id:" << this_id;
        std::cout << "\nThen Task: Start";
    });
```

In the above case the code crashes as follows.

```
>   ThreadPool_Boost.exe!boost::executors::executor_ref<boost::executors::executor>::submit(boost::detail::nullary_function<void __cdecl(void)> && closure={...}) Line 73   C++ Symbols loaded.
    [Inline Frame] ThreadPool_Boost.exe!boost::executors::executor::submit(boost::detail::run_it<boost::detail::continuation_shared_state<boost::future<void>,void,void <lambda>(boost::future<void>),boost::detail::shared_state<void>>> &&) Line 107  C++ Symbols loaded.
    ThreadPool_Boost.exe!boost::detail::future_executor_continuation_shared_state<boost::future<void>,void,void <lambda>(boost::future<void>)>::launch_continuation() Line 4711 C++ Symbols loaded.
    ThreadPool_Boost.exe!boost::detail::shared_state<void>::do_continuation(boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> & lock={...}) Line 853 C++ Symbols loaded.
    [Inline Frame] ThreadPool_Boost.exe!boost::detail::shared_state_base::mark_finished_internal(boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> &) Line 345   C++ Symbols loaded.
    [Inline Frame] ThreadPool_Boost.exe!boost::detail::shared_state<void>::mark_finished_with_result_internal(boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> &) Line 857  C++ Symbols loaded.
    ThreadPool_Boost.exe!boost::detail::shared_state<void>::mark_finished_with_result() Line 864    C++ Symbols loaded.
    ThreadPool_Boost.exe!boost::detail::task_shared_state<void <lambda>(void),void __cdecl(void)>::do_run() Line 3423   C++ Symbols loaded.
    [Inline Frame] ThreadPool_Boost.exe!boost::detail::task_base_shared_state<void __cdecl(void)>::run() Line 2995  C++ Symbols loaded.
    [Inline Frame] ThreadPool_Boost.exe!boost::packaged_task<void __cdecl(void)>::operator()() Line 3781    C++ Symbols loaded.
    ThreadPool_Boost.exe!boost::asio::asio_handler_invoke<boost::packaged_task<void __cdecl(void)>>(boost::packaged_task<void __cdecl(void)> & function, ...) Line 70   C++ Symbols loaded.
    [Inline Frame] ThreadPool_Boost.exe!boost_asio_handler_invoke_helpers::invoke(boost::packaged_task<void __cdecl(void)> &) Line 37   C++ Symbols loaded.
    [Inline Frame] ThreadPool_Boost.exe!boost::asio::system_executor::dispatch(boost::packaged_task<void __cdecl(void)> &&) Line 39 C++ Symbols loaded.
    [Inline Frame] ThreadPool_Boost.exe!boost::asio::detail::work_dispatcher<boost::packaged_task<void __cdecl(void)>>::operator()() Line 59    C++ Symbols loaded.
    ThreadPool_Boost.exe!boost::asio::asio_handler_invoke<boost::asio::detail::work_dispatcher<boost::packaged_task<void __cdecl(void)>>>(boost::asio::detail::work_dispatcher<boost::packaged_task<void __cdecl(void)>> & function={...}, ...) Line 69 C++ Symbols loaded.
    [Inline Frame] ThreadPool_Boost.exe!boost_asio_handler_invoke_helpers::invoke(boost::asio::detail::work_dispatcher<boost::packaged_task<void __cdecl(void)>> &) Line 37 C++ Symbols loaded.
    ThreadPool_Boost.exe!boost::asio::detail::executor_op<boost::asio::detail::work_dispatcher<boost::packaged_task<void __cdecl(void)>>,std::allocator<void>,boost::asio::detail::scheduler_operation>::do_complete(void * owner=0x011a61d8, boost::asio::detail::scheduler_operation * base=0x011af1c8, const boost::system::error_code & __formal={...}, unsigned int __formal=0x00000000) Line 70   C++ Symbols loaded.
    [Inline Frame] ThreadPool_Boost.exe!boost::asio::detail::scheduler_operation::complete(void *) Line 40  C++ Symbols loaded.
    ThreadPool_Boost.exe!boost::asio::detail::scheduler::do_run_one(boost::asio::detail::conditionally_enabled_mutex::scoped_lock & lock={...}, boost::asio::detail::scheduler_thread_info & this_thread={...}, const boost::system::error_code & ec={...}) Line 449    C++ Symbols loaded.
    ThreadPool_Boost.exe!boost::asio::detail::scheduler::run(boost::system::error_code & ec={...}) Line 200 C++ Symbols loaded.
    [Inline Frame] ThreadPool_Boost.exe!boost::asio::thread_pool::thread_function::operator()() Line 33 C++ Symbols loaded.
    ThreadPool_Boost.exe!boost::asio::detail::win_thread::func<boost::asio::thread_pool::thread_function>::run() Line 123   C++ Symbols loaded.
    ThreadPool_Boost.exe!boost::asio::detail::win_thread_function(void * arg=0x011a65a0) Line 128   C++ Symbols loaded.
    ucrtbase.dll!767b38df() Unknown Non-user code. Symbol loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
    ucrtbase.dll![Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for ucrtbase.dll] Unknown No symbols loaded.
    kernel32.dll!77b36359() Unknown Non-user code. Symbol loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
    ntdll.dll!77d88944()    Unknown Non-user code. Symbol loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
    ntdll.dll!77d88914()    Unknown Non-user code. Symbol loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
```

2. Using the variant of 'then' where we can mention executor:

```
fut.then(pool.get_executor(), [](boost::future<void> res) {  /* <---- This is line 62 */

        std::thread::id this_id = std::this_thread::get_id();
        std::cout << "\nThread Id:" << this_id;
        std::cout << "\nThen Task: Start";
    });
```

The above code fails to compile saying the following:

```
1>C:\Users\shtrived\Desktop\AsyncTask\ThreadPool_Boost\Demo.cpp(62,5): error C2664: 'boost::future<void> boost::future<void>::then<boost::asio::thread_pool::executor_type,main::<lambda_c8a45d8f92e13883b6218f06c9a06a8d>>(Ex &,F &&)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'boost::asio::thread_pool::executor_type' to 'boost::launch'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            Ex=boost::asio::thread_pool::executor_type,
1>            F=main::<lambda_c8a45d8f92e13883b6218f06c9a06a8d>
1>        ]
```

## Question:

1. Why the above run time and compile time errors ?
2. How to post the continuation correctly to the thread pool only ?

Full Sample Code:

```
#define BOOST_THREAD_PROVIDES_FUTURE
#define BOOST_THREAD_PROVIDES_SIGNATURE_PACKAGED_TASK
#define BOOST_THREAD_PROVIDES_VARIADIC_THREAD
#define BOOST_ERROR_CODE_HEADER_ONLY
#define BOOST_THREAD_PROVIDES_FUTURE_UNWRAP
#define BOOST_THREAD_PROVIDES_FUTURE_CONTINUATION
#define BOOST_RESULT_OF_USE_DECLTYPE
#define BOOST_THREAD_VERSION 4
#define BOOST_THREAD_PROVIDES_EXECUTORS   //on including this we start getting build errors

#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/future.hpp>
#include<iostream>
#include<thread>
#include<stdexcept> //only for testing
#include<vector>
//#include<boost/asio/executor.hpp>
#include<boost/asio.hpp>

int main()
{
    boost::asio::thread_pool pool(1);

    //This is the first function that we want to run on the thread pool 
    auto func = []() {
        cout << "\nTask in progress";
        std::thread::id this_id = std::this_thread::get_id();
        cout << "\nThread Id:" << this_id << " Task 1: Just a cout";
    };

    //Make a packaged task with the above function
    boost::packaged_task<void()> task(std::move(func));

    //Get the future from the packaged task
    boost::future<void> fut = task.get_future();

    //Post the task into the thread pool
    boost::asio::post(pool, std::move(task));

    /*
     * We want to run the continuation in the same thread pool
     */
    fut.then(pool.get_executor(), [](boost::future<void> res) {

        std::thread::id this_id = std::this_thread::get_id();
        std::cout << "\nThread Id:" << this_id;
        std::cout << "\nThen Task: Start";
    });

    pool.join();
    cout << "\nJoin Complete";
}
```

Comment: You should be able to copy the call stack into text (not an image) from the crash; that might be useful if posted in your question.

Comment: Also a [mcve] - where did `fut` cone from?

Comment: Thanks  @Yakk-AdamNevraumont  for looking into my query. I have attached the full crash stack and have also added more comments for clarity. The above code is as minimal as possible from my side.

Comment: `BOOST_THREAD_PROVIDES_EXECUTORS`